# Manipulate private field and access private method using PowerMockito

Tags: junit, mockito, private, powermockito, spy

I have a private boolean field that I'm trying to set to true by setting its internal state using PowerMockito or by using the private setter but neither are working. I put print statements in the logic to check the variable. I see that it is being set to true in my beforeclass but once the test hits a statement using the private field, it's false. What am I doing wrong?

```
SQLJConnectionBase spy = PowerMockito.spy( new SQLJConnectionBase());
System.out.println("current internal state - " + Whitebox.getInternalState(spy, "isJUnitTestCase"));
PowerMockito.doReturn(true).when(spy, "isJUnitTestCase");
Whitebox.setInternalState(spy, "isJUnitTestCase", true);
System.out.println("new internal state - " + Whitebox.getInternalState(spy, "isJUnitTestCase"));
```

Console output of the print statements in the test class before and after the manipulation of the private field in the beforeclass method:

```
current internal state - false
new internal state - true
```

Console output of the print statements in the class being tested in the method using the private method and private variable:

```
variable state - false
method call variable state - false
```

As you can see, isJUnitTest is being set to true in the beforeclass, but when the test case actually uses it, isJUnitTest is false.

These are my annotations on the test class

```
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.*")
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({SQLJConnectionBase.class})
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is `isJUnitTestCase` actually a field name?  It appears that you may possibly be specifying the setter method name, but you would need to give the field name for whatever field the isJUnitTestCase method sets.

See https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Bypass-Encapsulation for an example.

But if you are adding a member to the class you are testing that indicates if this is a unit test of not, you are doing something wrong in your class.  You shouldn't add test crud to a real class--there are other approaches to allow you to test your code without having to add such hooks.